# Can RXJS run without a server on (client side)?

Tags: javascript, rxjs6

Ok so this will seem silly but please help if you can.
I want to start using RXJS.

as opposed to vanilla javascript it doesnt seem to work by just downloading it and then importing from the local source file.
(simple example):

HTML:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="app.ts"></script>
    </body>
```

app.ts:

```
    // RxJS v6+
    import { interval } from 'rxjs';
    import { sample } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

I get an error though that this is a valid object (obviously because there is no rxjs loaded via the initial html page as a script)

QUESTION: What is a good way to load rxjs assuming that I want to create an offline site that the user downloads once and then uses the resources importing them from this local file (not all at once obviously) for route?

** I dont want to run a server on client side though if possible**

Thanks,
Alex

```
    HTML:

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="app.ts"></script>
    </body>
```

app.ts:

```
    // RxJS v6+
    import { interval } from 'rxjs';
    import { sample } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: I don't understand. If you have a library, it need to be imported somewhere in a script tag for instance. But the library is executing client side only. Maybe you are mixing up with for instance an Angular projct where all the libraries are bundled together in a big pack to be served.  I mean, to use "import" statements, you need to have the rxjs script imported.

Comment: check https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/installation (the last section "CDN")

Comment: Download minified verson and then put **script** tag to load it before your app.ts script tag. It executes sequential. First script tag for rxjs and then app.ts. now its availabe to use in app.ts but again its global variable. Not need to import from  syntaxes

Comment: Any Javascript file can be retrieve locally without internet. In your case, you are just using someone else's javascript file. You could download it and host it locally, retrieving it from your own computer when needing it ( `<script src="path/to/rxjs""></script>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, typescript doesn't run natively in the browser. You'll have to transpile it by configuring a [tsconfig.json](https://www.google.com/search?q=tsconfig&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS863US863&oq=tsconfig&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59.2255j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active), or using `babel` with the `typescript-preset`.

I recommend changing your file extensions to `js` for starters. Secondly, I recommend using something simple to bundle your ES6 imports into something the browser can read, like [Parcel](https://www.google.com/search?q=parcel&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS863US863&oq=parcel&aqs=chrome..69i57.863j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active). If you choose to use native [ES6 modules](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/), you'll need to link to RXJS in your index.html file, and whatever dependencies it may require, rather than using a `package.json`.

All that said, I recommend getting your feet wet with Parcel. It will generate a single `js` file that is the sum of all of your dependencies. And that `js` file can be referenced in the script tag of your `index.html` file.

Here's their Getting Started guide:
https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at a framework like electron. You can create executable applications for OS like windows or iOS with that. There are some initial scaffolds out there which you can easily find via google. Start with them and add rxjs with npm or yarn.

Nothing can stop you, keep ahead.

( I had make a electron application in the past and it works better then expected )